# Getting the top level and second level domain of a URL in regex

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I am trying to use regex to return the end of a URL. For example: 
google.com should return com
google.co.uk  should return co.uk

I can extract google.com using this regex: [^.]+(?=.$|$)
Can a regular expression actually take into account co.uk and not just return the last value? 
I have researched on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ but it did not seem to be of any help, hence my question

I am trying to do this in pig.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please precise the language you use (and read the description of the [regex] tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution :

```
(?:\.)([^\.]{1,3}\.?[^\.]*)$
```

Examples in JavaScript (you didn't precise the language) :

```
"google.co.uk".match(/(?:\.)([^\.]{1,3}\.?[^\.]*)$/).pop() => "co.uk"
"google.com".match(/(?:\.)([^\.]{1,3}\.?[^\.]*)$/).pop() => "com"
"a.google.com".match(/(?:\.)([^\.]{1,3}\.?[^\.]*)$/).pop() => "com"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This unfortunatly doens't work when I test it on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ google.com returns google.com, google.co.uk returns co.uk.

Comment: Note that you have a simple tool in the console of your browser : paste `"google.co.uk".match(/(?:\.)([^\.]*\.?[^\.]*)$/).pop()`.

Comment: Can't argue with that. Don't know why mine didn't work. Thankyou

Comment: f.goole.com would return google.com instead of com? Just curious more than anything: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?372tm

Comment: Well... that's logical due to your specification... What exactly do you want ?

Comment: Ideally anylength URL but will return either com, or .co.uk (if it ends in .co.uk)
In java its easy as you can split the url up and look at the end, check the length and then return .com or .co.uk depending on the size of the last value. Hopefully that made sense. Thanks

e.g              
f.d.f.g.facebook.com would return com
   stackoverflow.co.uk would return co.uk

Comment: You mean you want to have only tokens with at most 3 digits ? Then the edited answer should be what you look for.